# AUS/UK dual citizen entering the UK on AUS visa with student visa and taking partner as dependant

Tags: visas, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, study, australian-citizens

I've been accepted on a full scholarship to do my Doctorate in the UK in Oxbridge. I am a UK/AUS citizen but my partner is only an AUS citizen.

Can I apply to enter the UK under my AUS passport with a student visa and have my partner as a dependent or will I not be allowed because of my UK citizenship?

Comment: This is off topic here.  You can ask at [Expatriates.SE].